# Mimosa - Change name of minified asset at compiled dir

Tags: minify, mimosa

I've found Mimosa past month but now I am finally starting to use it.

Consider this configuration snippet:

```
exports.config = {
  "modules": [
    "copy",
    "minify-js"
  ],
  "watch": {
    "sourceDir": "src",
    "compiledDir": "dist",
    "javascriptDir": null
  }
}
```

The JavaScript assets from `src` are minified and saved at `dist` with the exact same name: `src/foo.js` is minified as `dist/foo.js`.

I would like to have both the minified file as `.min.js` and also the original unchanged and copied file at the compiled dir.

For example: `src/bar.js` becomes `dist/bar.min.js` (minified) and `dist/bar.js` (copy).

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1):

So that isn't something mimosa, or more specifically mimosa-minify-js will do.

What is your use case?  Are you building libraries?  I can either help you get what you need or I could see what I'd need to do to support what you want.